Connect SSMS to Azure SQL Database
I am trying to connect my Azure SQL database to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Getting the error: Connection host has failed to respond

Cannot connect to {my server}.database.windows.net.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I tried putting my IP address in the allowed IP address list in the firewall settings in Azure portal but it is still not working. Could someone help me how to resolve this problem. Also my main aim is to connect the Azure SQL database to a python environment. Will this error affect my connection with python as well?
Also, any alternative method is surely appreciated.

Did you provide correct details of SQL server?

Check if Azure SQL database have configured with VPN setting.
Will this error affect my connection with python as well?
It depends based on how the Azure SQL access is configured, if you have configured it to access within the same resources or VPN or same subscription and if your code is deployed in the Azure based on the above configuration it can connect to the database.
But it will affect your local development, see if you have enabled public access

